# Declaração de Ponteiros numa struct e chamando o mesmo em função

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, struct

Devo resolver o seguinte problema criando uma funcão para leitura, uma para cálculo e utilizar ponteiros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct ponto
{
    int x;
    int y;
}ponto1, ponto2;
struct ponto *p1, *p2;
p1 = &ponto1;
p2 = &ponto2;

void ler(struct ponto *p1, *p2)
{
    printf("Digite o valor de X1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &p1 -> x);
    printf("Digite o valor de Y1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &p1 -> y);
    printf("Digite o valor de X1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &p2 -> x);
    printf("Digite o valor de Y1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &p2 -> y);
}

int calculo(struct ponto *p1, *p2)
{
    int a, b, d;
    a = (*p1).x - (*p2).x;
    b = (*p1).y - (*p2).y;

    d = sqrt(pow(a,2)+pow(b,2));

    printf("%d", d);
}

int main()
{
    ler(struct ponto *p1, *p2);
    calculo(struct ponto *p1, *p2);
    return 0;
}
```

porém eu já tentei de tantas maneiras diferentes e continua apresentando os mesmos erros. São eles;

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
|11|warning: data definition has no type or storage class|
|11|warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'p1' [-Wimplicit-int]|
|11|error: conflicting types for 'p1'|
|10|note: previous declaration of 'p1' was here|
|11|warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
|12|warning: data definition has no type or storage class|
|12|warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'p2' [-Wimplicit-int]|
|12|error: conflicting types for 'p2'|
|10|note: previous declaration of 'p2' was here|
|12|warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
|14|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token|
|30|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token|
||In function 'main':|
|43|warning: implicit declaration of function 'ler' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
|43|error: expected expression before 'struct'|
|44|warning: implicit declaration of function 'calculo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
|44|error: expected expression before 'struct'|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 8 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Quais as maneiras que tentou?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno, beleza? \o/

A sua lógica ta excelente. Só que a forma que você definiu algumas coisas ocasionou certas incompatibilidades de tipo. Antes de prosseguirmos, **você precisa mesmo trabalhar com variáveis globais?** Se não, vamos relembrar um conceito bacana de função:

> Variáveis definidas dentro de uma função são variáveis locais.

Partindo dessa afirmação, temos que o "tempo de vida" de uma variável local é relativo ao tempo de execução da função onde foi definida. Certo. Pegando o seu exemplo, se os ponteiros para as estruturas ponto1 e ponto2 forem criados na *main* e as chamadas das funções *ler()* e *calculo()* forem realizadas dentro desse mesmo escopo, temos que as respectivas funções terão acesso às informações necessárias, pois os ponteiros p1 e p2 existirão enquanto a *main* for executada. Em tese, será possível atribuir valores às estruturas apontadas por p1 e p2 e utilizar esses valores no cálculo da distância entre dois pontos.

Antes de mostrar como ficaram as modificações no seu código, ressalto alguns erros cometidos:

i.  Declaração incorreta de parâmetros para a função

```
void ler(struct ponto *p1, *p2)

int calculo(struct ponto *p1, *p2)
```

Nessa etapa, ao menos na Linguagem C, é necessário que a listagem dos nomes dos parâmetros seja precedida por seu tipo. No caso, você somente fez isso para o ponteiro p1. Mesmo que p2 seja do mesmo tipo de p1, é necessário fazer essa redundância de código.

ii. Especificador de tipo inadequado

```
int calculo(struct ponto *p1, *p2)
```

A função *calculo()*, ao menos na sua lógica, não retorna nada para a função que realizou a sua chamada. Assim, o especificador de tipo mais adequado é o *void*. Caso tenha pretensão de retornar o valor da distância entre os dois pontos, utilize o *return*.

iii. Declaração incorreta de argumentos para a função

```
ler(struct ponto *p1, *p2);
```

Quando a chamada de uma função for realizada, não é necessário especificar o tipo dos argumentos. Isso somente é necessário na declaração dos parâmetros, que são variáveis que receberão a cópia dos argumentos. Ah, e como p1 e p2 são ponteiros, não há necessidade de utilizar o operador * neste caso.

Então, agora que os erros foram expostos, o seu código ficou desta forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct ponto
{
    int x;
    int y;
}ponto1, ponto2;

void ler(struct ponto *p1, struct ponto *p2)
{
    printf("Digite o valor de X1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &p1 -> x);
    printf("Digite o valor de Y1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &p1 -> y);
    printf("Digite o valor de X1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &p2 -> x);
    printf("Digite o valor de Y1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &p2 -> y);
}

void calculo(struct ponto *p1, struct ponto *p2)
{
    int a, b, d;
    a = (*p1).x - (*p2).x;
    b = (*p1).y - (*p2).y;

    d = sqrt(pow(a,2)+pow(b,2));

    printf("%d", d);
}

int main()
{
    struct ponto *p1, *p2;
    p1 = &ponto1;
    p2 = &ponto2;

    ler(p1, p2);
    calculo(p1, p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Espero que tenha sido claro, amigo.

Um abraço =]

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado, você foi bem claro e objetivo. Eu não sabia que podia deixar os ponteiros no main, você expandiu a minha mente. eu estou desde sábado tentando resolver esse problema, muito obrigado mesmo!!!